# G++ how to compile a .h that is in a different directory with .cpp

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, makefile, g++

G++ how to compile a .h that is in a different directory with .cpp
for example i got folders which are "header" and "src", in header folder have my .h , and src have all my .cpp also my main.cpp is there.

Comment: option `-I` of g++ at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
g++ -I header src/main.cpp src/other.cpp
```

Now your .cpp files can do something like this:

```
#include <blah.h>
```

And they will find `header/blah.h`.

Comment: is that possible to do in a makefile ?

Comment: omg, seriously because i'm new in these g++ can u show me the complete makefile code ? :\ for example: header folder will have > prime.h and src folder will have prime.cpp and main.cpp.

Comment: @user3551743: no, I will not write your Makefile for you.  There are lots of tutorials for that.  Or even better, use CMake to write your Makefile automatically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all .h are never compiled only source files are compiled. You can include the relative path of that header in your source file. For e.g :_

```
sys.cpp 

#include "../header/sys.h"
```

EDITED :-

@Lightness races in orbit :-

What I learnt in my childhood is when we compile a program first pre-processor comes into picture which  expands .h file in sorce files wherever they are included. And then resulting source file is given to compiler and then further processing goes on. So compiler doesn't even know what .h file is. Please correct me if I have forgotten/ mis understood somethinbg

Comment: Headers are absolutely compiled. It's just that they're compiled somewhat indirectly.

Comment: My guess is that @ravi meant that usually translation units are made with source files, not purely include files (with the idea that an include file is any file used with a `#include` directive). That said, a compiler will not pay much attention to the file extension if instructed so, and the processor allows pretty much anything.

Comment: can u write a simple makefile code here ? :\
example header file have prime.h and src file have prime.cpp and main.cpp